# Python script to automate influxdb backups

Tags: python, backup, influxdb

I'm looking for a way to automate the backup of my InfluxDB databases via Python.
Did anyone has done it yet? 
Or it doesn't make any sense to do it via Python and I should just stick to a bash script (like this one: https://gist.github.com/opHASnoNAME/7b367abfbba8b34f3591842db8814a8f)?

Comment: What are you hoping Python will give you that a shell script won't?

Answer (score -1):

I have finished such a script recently, running it for influxdb and mongodb hourly by jenkins.

There are two folders to store the backups.

One named "hourly_backups" stores the latest 24 hourly backups.

Another one named "daily_backups" holds the earliest hourly backup of last 7 days.

After backup is successfully finished, it will clean the old files to control the total size.

It sounds easy but must be careful.

I agreed that bash better for use. But you can also do it in python as a training.

People who has questions about the backups scripts of these two dbs can discuss it with me.

Comment: can you share a github link